# Why do I get all 0s when I print the arrays?

Tags: java

When I call my last method called `print`, all it does is print all 0s from the arrays. Not sure how to fix it exactly. In my instructions it had method `print` with parameters of `(double[] noGreen, double[] green, double[] diff)`.

If anyone could show me how to fix this and explain what I did wrong would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class lab7{
    public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner kb =  new Scanner(System.in);
      run(kb);
    }
    public static void run(Scanner kb){
      double[] a = new double[12];
      double[] b = new double[12];
      double[] diff = new double[12];
      fillArray(kb, a, "Enter the amount for Before going green :");
      fillArray(kb, b, "Enter the amount for After going green: "); 
      getDiff(a, b);
      print(a, b, diff);
    }
    public static int getValidInt(Scanner kb, String month){
      while (true) {
         System.out.print(month + " --> ");
         if (kb.hasNextInt()){
            int num = Integer.valueOf(kb.nextLine());
            if (num >0){
               return num;
            }else if(num <=0){
               System.out.print(month + " --> ");
               num = Integer.valueOf(kb.nextLine());
               return num;
            }
         }
         kb.nextLine();
      }
    }
    public static void fillArray(Scanner kb, double[] a, String prompt){
      System.out.println(prompt);
      System.out.println("You must enter a positive amount for each month.");
      String[] month = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
      for (int i = 0; i < month.length; i++){
         getValidInt(kb, month[i]);
      }
    }
    public static double[] getDiff(double[] a, double[] b){
      double[] diff = new double[12];
      for(int i =0; i< a.length; i++){
         diff[i] = a[i] - b[i];
      }
      return diff;
    }
    public static void dashes(){
      for(int i = 1; i <= 40; i++){
         System.out.print("-");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    public static void print(double[] a, double[] b, double[] diff){
      System.out.println("Here is the summary of your saving");
      System.out.printf("%-11s%9s%10s%10s\n", "Month", "No Green", "Green", "Saving");
      dashes();
      String[] month = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
      for(int i = 0; i < month.length; i++){
         System.out.printf("%-10s%8.2f%10.2f%10.2f\n", month[i], a[i], b[i], diff[i]);
      }
      dashes();
      System.out.println();

    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you fillArray() method doesn't use the array that it receives as argument, and the getDiff() method only reads from the two arrays and subtracts them (but 0 - 0 = 0).

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign the return values of your methods to your variables. This means you never changed `a`, `b` and `diff`.

In `run`, assign `getDiff` to `diff`:

```
  double[] diff = getDiff(a, b);
```

This also means that you can delete this declaration a few lines above:

```
  double[] diff = new double[12];
```

In `fillArray`, assign `getValidInt` to `a[i]`:

```
a[i] = getValidInt(kb, month[i]);
```

Comment: ahhhhh!!! that worked.... that's weird since I tried    a[I] = getValidInt(kb, month[I[); earlier but it gave me a error

Comment: Thank you helping me understand how to use arrays better.

Comment: @C.Ramirez Your attempt is in the right direction, but you didn't assign `diff`, did you? That's why it didn't work.

Comment: @C.Ramirez If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

In your `public static void fillArray(Scanner kb, double[] a, String prompt)` method you are sending a `double` array parameter named as `a` but inside that method you have never used that parameter. So when you called that method with the array you created, that array is never filled. So still the array is filled with the default value of `double` when you have created the array first time

Maybe you have to assign the value of this call `getValidInt(kb, month[i]);` to the `a` variable

About your get `getDiff(a, b)` call, you have called it but you haven't assigned it to `diff` variable like this, `diff = getDiff(a, b);`